# Ruby On Rails: Storing collection_select values into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I have a form that has multiple collect_select fields and I want to be able to store the selected values into an array or hash.

So for example:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:package_ids, Package.all, :id, :concatTitle, {:prompt => true}) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:package_ids, Package.all, :id, :concatTitle, {:prompt => true}) %>  
<%= f.collection_select(:package_ids, Package.all, :id, :concatTitle, {:prompt => true}) %>
```

I want all the selected id's to be stored into the same field `:package_ids`. What would be the correct syntax to do this?